# How to call method from different class within a print statement?

Tags: java

I am a beginner to java and I am trying to build a smoking saving calculator of some sorts. I am trying to get used to using objects in java but I do not know how I call a method form a different class within a print statement in the main method. I have tried looking online for an answer but I failed to find one that suits me case.

**SMOKING CALC**

```
public class SmokingCalc {

 public static void main(String args[]) {

    System.out.println("********SMOKING CALCULATOR********");

    Calc cost = new Calc(getPackets, getWeek, getCost);

    System.out.println("How much is a packet of cigarretes?");

    cost.getCost();

    System.out.println("How many packets do you smoke a week?");

    cost.getWeek();

    System.out.println("You would save " + getWeek + "units in one week." );

    }
}
```

**Calc**

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Calc {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
private int packs;
private int weekly;
private int cost;

public Calc(int getPacks, int getCost, int getWeekly) {

    int input = scan.nextInt();
    int input1 = scan.nextInt();
    int input2 = scan.nextInt();

    packs = input;
    weekly = input1;
    cost = input2;
}
public int getPackets() {

    return packs;
}

public int getWeek() {

    return weekly;
}

public int getCost() {

    return cost;
}

public int fourWeeksCost() {
    int fourWeek;
    fourWeek = 4 * cost;
    return fourWeek;
}

public int twelveWeekCost() {
    int twelveWeek;
    twelveWeek = 12 * cost;
    return twelveWeek;
}

public int sixMonthsCost() {
    int sixMonths;
    sixMonths = 26 * cost;
    return sixMonths;
}

public int yearlyCost() {
    int yearly;
    yearly = 52 * cost;
    return yearly;
}

}
```

I would appreciate any help on how to do this, thanks in advance.

Comment: System.out.println("How much is a packet of cigarretes?" + cost.getCost()); then repeat for the rest.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.

Comment: suppose your code won't compile. where you suppose to pass values to the constructor `Calc cost = new Calc(getPackets, getWeek, getCost);` with out getting inputs.

Comment: How do I fix this? I got input within those methods in the other class. How do i transfer the information from there to the constructor?

Comment: what is the purpose of `getWeek` ?

Comment: To see how many packets the user smokes in a week.

Comment: @AlanPiggott i added a solution.

Answer (score 0):

suppose this may be a solution for your problem.

Calc.Java

```
public class Calc {
private int packs;
private int costPerPack;
private int costPerWeek;

public Calc(int getPacks, int cost ) {

    packs = getPacks;
    costPerPack = cost;
    costPerWeek = getPacks * cost;
}
public int getPackets() {

    return packs;
}

public int getCostPerPack() {

    return costPerPack;
}

public int getCostPerWeek() {

    return costPerWeek;
}

public int fourWeeksCost() {
    int fourWeek;
    fourWeek = 4 * costPerWeek;
    return fourWeek;
}

public int twelveWeekCost() {
    int twelveWeek;
    twelveWeek = 12 * costPerWeek;
    return twelveWeek;
}

public int sixMonthsCost() {
    int sixMonths;
    sixMonths = 26 * costPerWeek;
    return sixMonths;
}

public int yearlyCost() {
    int yearly;
    yearly = 52 * costPerWeek;
    return yearly;
}

}
```

SmokingCalc.java

```
public class SmokingCalc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int costforpack,packs;

        System.out.println("********SMOKING CALCULATOR********");


        System.out.println("How much is a packet of cigarretes?");

        costforpack = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("How many packets do you smoke a week?");

        packs = scan.nextInt();

        Calc cost = new Calc(packs, costforpack );

        System.out.println("You would save " + cost.getCostPerWeek() + "units in one week." );


        }
}
```

Hope this helps.